# MS Access: Saving data after displaying on a form

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, conditional-statements

I have the following 3 tables:

Retailer:
RetailerID
RetailerName
Taxable(YES or NO)

Product:
Stake
AmountWithTax
AmountWithoutTax

Refund:
RetailerID (lookup values from Retailer as a dropdown list)
ProductName (lookup values from Product as a dropdown list)

I have a query, called RefundQuery, that takes from these 3 tables:
Refund - RetailerID, ProductName
Retailer - RetailerName, Taxable
Product - Stake, AmountWithTax, AmountWithoutTax

A form is then created based on RefundQuery. The idea is to have a user select the RetailerID from a dropdown list, which populates the fields RetailerName and Taxable automatically. The user will then select a ProductName from a dropdown list and key in a value for Stake, which then auto-populates the values for both AmountWithTax and AmountWithoutTax. However, I do not how to display just one of the values, depending on whether the Retailer is Taxable or not.

I have tried to create an additional Textbox in the form and added
=IIf([Taxable]="YES",[AmountWithTax],[AmountWithoutTax])
into the control source. While this displays the corresponding value, it does not save into my records. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is Taxable a Yes/No (Boolean) type field? If it is then don't need the `="Yes"`, just:

`=IIf([Taxable], [AmountWithTax], [AmountWithoutTax])`

However, since you say your expression is working I guess it is a text type field.

Saving is not necessary unless these values are subject to change over time. If you must save then that requires code in some event. You also need a field in appropriate table (maybe Refund) to save into.

`Me!Amount = Me.textboxname`

The real trick is figuring out what event. Perhaps the AfterUpdate event of Stake textbox.

Stake combobox is where you select product name?

Comment: Taxable is a YES or NO text. I need the value to be saved so that at the end, a user can export these data into a .csv file. I have also tried adding another field called FinalRefundArmount for the value to be saved but it does not save. Stake combobox is when a user types in an amount.